# Cannot install visual studio on Ubuntu 20.04 WSL2?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 WSL2 on my Windows 10 machine.  All I've done so far is `update` and `upgrade`, and installed a few packages so I can use the GUI version of Ubuntu applications.  I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@japheth.yates/the-complete-wsl2-gui-setup-2582828f4577) for the GUI if you want to know what I did, skipping the part about making a file `/etc/sudoers.d/dbus`

I tried running `sudo snap install --classic code` but I get `error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/code: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory`

I found that I should check if `snapd` is running, when I run `systemctl status snapd` I get `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down`

I just tried an alternative method of installing VSCode with `sudo apt install code` but I get this message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package code
```

I thought maybe it needed be shutdown and retsarted, I did that to my whole laptop but to no avail. I also tried to restart/shutdown inside the terminal after the fact with `sudo shutdown -r` and I get the same error -

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Any thoughts on what could be going wrong?

Comment: What happens if you do systemctl start snapd.service and then try using snap for installation.

Comment: Tried that command with and without sudo and I get the same error - `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down`

Answer (score 2):

When using WSL, you really want to install the Windows version of VSCode.  It provides tight integration with WSL through the WSL/Windows interop features.  When installed under Windows, you can still access it from WSL with a simple:

```
code .
```

This is provided by a shell script in the `VSCode/bin` directory that WSL will run, which in turn bootstraps the Windows executable.  The first time you run it, it will install a lightweight server inside WSL for some additional interop.

Once installed, add in the *Remote Development* extension pack.  This includes the *Remote - WSL*, *Remote - Containers*, and *Remote - SSH* extensions.  You can open files directly from the WSL filesystem, start a WSL terminal from within VSCode, etc.

As for the Linux version of VSCode, the problems you are running into are because WSL does not support Systemd (neither version 1 nor version2) nor Snap without extensive additional effort (that honestly, I've never found it worthwhile to do).